# Объясните каждую строчку в методе shellSort

Tags: c#, сортировка

Рассматриваю пример изучения на практике алгоритмов сортировок. Не могу разобраться с циклами. Пожалуйста, объясните каждую строчку в методе shellSort.
Сортировка Шелла - модифицированная сортировка вставками. Разбивается на три этапа с определенными шагами, которые можно определить разными способами.Например в данном случае d=3(arr[0],arr[3],arr[6]) d=2 d=1. C каждым шагом делается сортировка вставками, сортируя и поэтапно приближая массив к отсортированному.

```
class SortShell
{
    public static void SubMain(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 5, -4, 11, 0, 18, 22, 67, 51, 6 };
        int n;

        n = arr.Length;
        Console.WriteLine("Original Array Elements :");
        show_array_elements(arr);
        shellSort(arr, n);
        Console.WriteLine("\nSorted Array Elements :");
        show_array_elements(arr);
    }

    static void shellSort(int[] arr, int array_size)
    {
        int i, j, inc, temp;
        inc = 3;                  
        while (inc > 0)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
            {
                j = i;
                temp = arr[i];
                while ((j >= inc) && (arr[j - inc] > temp)
                {
                    arr[j] = arr[j - inc];
                    j = j - inc;
                }
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
            if (inc / 2 != 0)
                inc = inc / 2;
            else if (inc == 1)
                inc = 0;
            else
                inc = 1;
        }
    }

    static void show_array_elements(int[] arr)
    {
        foreach (var element in arr)
        {
            Console.Write(element + " ");
        }
        Console.Write("\n");

    }
}
```

Comment: может лучше не с практики начинать, а с теории? :-)

Comment: Я разобрался с самой сортировкой. А вот код сам написать не могу. Если кто может обьяснить код буду очень благодарен

Comment: Опиши, в вопросе, как ты понял саму сортировку.

Comment: Но ведь каждая строчка объяснена в книжках и курсах по алгоритмам. Зачем их дублировать?

Comment: Откуда дровишки про **три** этапа?

Comment: Три этапа  в примере который рассматривается, этапов должно столько сколько нужно чтобы дойти до шага равному 1. Возможно их может быть больше.
В любом случае этот вопрос остается не ясен для меня и поэтому решил задать вопрос. 
К сожалению из стоящих ответов только, если перефразировать ищи книги и думай сам.

Answer (score 0):

```
 static void shellSort(int[] arr, int array_size)
    {
        int i, j, inc, temp;// объявление переменных
        inc = 3;//присвоение значения для переменной                  
        while (inc > 0)//цикл с предусловием. будет работать пока условие истинно
        {
            for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++)//задается начальное значение индекса,границы этого значения, и шаг изменения индекса после каждого прохода цикла
            {
                j = i; // присвоение
                temp = arr[i]; // в переменную записываем определенное значение массива индекс которого i.  Если  і = 5   то соответственно это пятый элемент массива
                while ((j >= inc) && (arr[j - inc] > temp)// для этого цикла уже два условия и он буде работать пока их совместный результат будет правдив
                {
                    arr[j] = arr[j - inc]; 
                    j = j - inc;
                }
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
            if (inc / 2 != 0)//условие, код условия выполнится когда условие правдиво
                inc = inc / 2;
            else if (inc == 1) //если первое условие не правдиво то проверяется это
                inc = 0;
            else // если никакое из условий выше не сработало то будет выполнен код этого условия
                inc = 1;
        }
    }
```